# Jar Can't Find Main Class

Tags: java, groovy

I get: `Could not find the main class: org.dav.kin.Tester. Program will exit.` when I attempt to run my jar file via `java -jar tester.jar` **or** `java -classpath tester.jar org.dav.kin.Tester` Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it? Below are additional details. Thanks.

**Manifest File:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: DKin
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: org.dav.kin.Tester
```

**jar tf tester.jar**

```
org/
org/dav/
org/dav/kin/
org/dav/kin/Tester.class
org/dav/kin/TesterCellRenderer.class
...
...
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

**UPDATE:**

Jar file runs if I specify the system classpath, which contains the `groovy-all-{version}.jar`, like so: `java -classpath tester.jar;"%CLASSPATH%" org.dav.kin.Tester` Anyone know why I have to explicitly re-state the classpath (or more precisely, the groovy jar)?

Comment: Show output from `jar tf tester.jar`

Comment: make sure that last line is "Main-Class: org.dav.kin.Tester\r\n", just  a newline alone doesn't work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar file lacks a file with this name

```
/org/dav/kin/Tester.class
```

or you have special characters in your MANIFEST.MF file

MANIFEST.MF files have a particular syntax.  It's best to use other tools to generate them; however some of the details I've encountered which increases the success of hand written files include:

1. Always make sure the lines are less than 72 characters long.
2. Always use \r\n (windows newline), even on non-windows systems.
3. Verify that all whitespace characters are spaces.
4. Verify that there are no nonprintable characters (htab, etc).
5. Sometimes a blank line at the end of the file helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is Tester.class' package declaration org.dav.kin?

Comment: Yes, the `Tester` source file contains the `org.dav.kin` package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated that the you are using Groovy. Groovy does compile down to Java class files but it still requires the groovy runtime libraries. You need to make sure groovy is on the classpath as well as your classes. Try this:

```
java -classpath tester.jar;groovy-all-1.8.0.jar org.dav.kin.Tester
```

Comment: My system variable "CLASSPATH" does include `groovy-all-1.8.0.jar`. However, the jar only runs if I specify the system classpath, which includes the groovy jar like so: `java -classpath tester.jar;"%CLASSPATH%" org.dav.kin.Tester`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. I just solve exactly the same problem.
Instead of

```
Class-Path: .
```

in `MANIFEST.MF`

one should enumerate (**with space**) jars which are required in runtime, so it should be something like this:

```
Class-Path: groovy-all-2.4.5.jar relative/my-dependent-project-artifact.jar
```